# Javascript replace a string with a function

Tags: javascript, replace

For example, i have:

```
var obj = { "Age": "{{Range(20, 50)}}" }

getRandomRange = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

I want to replace `{{Range(20, 50)}}` with function `getRandomRange(20,50)`, something like this:

```
var new_obj = str.replace( /{{Range(x, y)}}/g, getRandomRange(x, y) );
```

Expected result: `obj = { "Age": "30" }`

How do i do this, could this be achieved with `replace()` only?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you replace it will be a string. The function will not be called or callable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the JSON string and replace the placeholder with a call of the function.

```js
const
    json = '{ "Age": "{{Range(20, 50)}}" }',
    getRandomRange = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min,
    placeholder = /\{\{Range\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)\}\}/g,
    targetjson = json.replace(placeholder, (_, x, y) => getRandomRange(+x, +y));

console.log(JSON.parse(targetjson));
```

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz. Your solution is worked. Thank you.
Can you explain this part ```(_, x, y) => getRandomRange(+x, +y)```. I'm not quite understand this function call.

Comment: the replacement function gets the paramter from the regular expression. this returns three parts: the first contains all matched values, the second the first group, the forthcoming first parameter `x` and the other group for the second parameter. by keeping your random function, it need another function to hand over the parameter and the wanted type as numbers.

Comment: I get it now.
Thanks @Nina.

Answer (score 0):

This is too much to put into a comment so I'm going to explain why its not working here:

**1. str is not a string.**

- Rename it because it can be msleading.

```
var obj = { "Age": "{{Range(20, 50)}}" }
```

**2. replace method returns a string, not an object**

- rename your variable to str.
- Also, special characters need to be backslahed: \{
- Also your method is being invoked, not actually being passed to the callback. Pass: getRandomRange not getRandomeRange(x, y)
- also - because you have 1 parenthesis in your regex below, it would return 2 arguments 0 and 1, but 1 is both (x, y), 0 = the whole match - {{Range(x, y)}}

```
var str = str.replace( /\{\{Range(x, y)\}\}/g, getRandomRange );
```

**3. How to extract something close to your requirement?**

- you don't need regex

```
getRandomRange = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var obj = {"Age": getRandomRange(20, 50)}
```

**4. if you want your result to be a string of a number**

```
getRandomRange = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var obj = {"Age": String(getRandomRange(20, 50))}
```

**Lastly:**
Be clare or 'clear' about your types. string, object, number.

Comment: sr i've named it wrong. already edit my question.
the reason for this is because i need to replace template inside double brackets {{ }} with a function.

Comment: @BaoPham You cannot do it with regex. The return of a replace method will be a string, not an object

Comment: i have my answer with NinaScholz helped. Thanks

Comment: @BaoPham That's good. Though I'd say its not a practice that should be encouraged. I say that as someone who loves regex, but this is not something I would ever do. I would encourage understanding simpler solutions.

Comment: can you provide me a solution to replace a template variable with a function call without using regex? I would appreciate it if it's simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @BaoPham Sure - post a new question based just on that. I am happy to look at it. Currently my solution to your above question I stand by.